# use templates but keep jquery bindings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, backbone.js

I currently have a LARGE single-page application, with each html "view" being built purely with jQuery DOM creation/manipulation. The javascript files are ridiculously large, and adding or changing a view is a very complex process. I started thinking about using backbone.js and templating. However, if I use templating, will I lose the ability to bind jQuery events and data to elements?

Comment: As long as you keep binding your events after your template is rendered, there is no problem at all. I'm actually using a lot of backbone with its template system, and binding events with jQuery, I never had any problem at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can still apply all your jQuery magic to your resulting DOM elements. Templating will simplify the process of creating DOM elements, but the result is the same and can be used identically.

Comment: so i'd have to go back with a bunch of jquery and add the events. doesn't seem there is much advantage to using templates in my case then

Comment: Templates will be an advantage when creating complex views but also in many cases allow for much more verbose code: you typically write your views in HTML (as opposed to JS strings), some of the languages (e.g. Mustache and Handlebars) provide separation of data and view structure.

Comment: now what would be the recommended method of storing and retrieving all these large, complex views? I'l like to store each view in it's own file for easy organization during development, and in production compile them for optimization.

Comment: You could store them as plain HTML and retrieve them on demand. There are plenty of resources on organizing your Backbone project files, check e.g. [Organizing your application using Modules](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules). Also, file concatenation/compression can be done in various ways, see e.g. [require.js's optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html).

Comment: how would you use require to pull in html files?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you lose any capability if you are using templates with jQuery? You can instantiate  elements via templates, and bind away as you always have - at template time or via preset `.live()` handlers.

Although I would take a look to make sure `Backbone.Router` doesn't give you a more elegant way to handle your interactions.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is a bottleneck issue, inline your events in your template.

`<input type="button" onclick="doit(this);">`